# UIButton's in loops, event only firing on first element

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, uibutton

I'm following along with a tutorial but having a problem with some buttons initialized in a for-loop.

I am applying an event to each of the buttons. But only the first button event is being fired?

Either the tutorial is wrong or I'm missing something.

```
// MARK: Properties
var rating = 0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}

var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
var spacing       = 5
var stars         = 5

// MARK: Initialization
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let emptyStarImage = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")
    let filledStarImage = UIImage(named: "filledStar")

    for _ in 0..<stars {
        let button = UIButton()

        button.setImage(emptyStarImage, forState: .Normal)
        button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: .Selected)
        button.setImage(filledStarImage, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

        button.addTarget(self, action: "ratingButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        ratingButtons += [button]

        addSubview(button)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Set the button's width and height to a square the size of the frame's height.
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
    var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)


    // Offset each button's origin by the length of the button plus some spacing.
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
        print(button)
        buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + 5))
        button.frame = buttonFrame
    }

    updateButtonSelectionStates()
}

// MARK: Button Action
func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {

    print('I have been clicked') // Can only see on the first button click
    rating = ratingButtons.indexOf(button)! + 1
    updateButtonSelectionStates()
}

func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
        // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button shouldn't be selected.
        button.selected = index < rating
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are not setting the frames to these buttons!. How do they look in UI? Must be overlapping one one another?

Comment: Sorry, I added the layoutSubviews() (should of included this in the original question) ... The buttons are rendered next to each other not on top of each other

Comment: Probably your super view is not resized to contain all buttons out there. Looks like all buttons but the first one are out side of the bounds of superview. Can you check?

Comment: I ran your code and I could click on all buttons.  Only 3 buttons were visible unless I rotated my simulator to landscape

Comment: It turns out I had a constraint on the view controller that seemed to be messing up the 'view port' accessable width / removed it and all is good

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a constraint on the view controller that seemed to be messing up the 'view port' accessable width / removed it and all is good

Answer (score 0):

i think your button is too big , you can only click on just only one of them. by the way ,why not choose override init(frame: CGRect)  as Initialization ...